# To get data to another page from a dynamic table by use of jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

[The following table is dynamically made with the use of jsp, i have shared the code below. I want that on the press of the button i get my selected required values on the other page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAtws.png)

```
code:

<form action="quotation.jsp" method="post">
    <table class="highlight centered responsive-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <%  
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            while(rs1.next())
            {
                i++;
                out.print("<th>"+rs1.getString(1)+"</th>");
            }
            j=i;
        %>
            <th> Quotation </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% 
            while(rs2.next())
            {
                out.println("<tr>");
                for(int q=1;q<=j;q++)
                {   
                    out.print("<td>"+rs2.getString(q)+"</td>");
                }
                %>
                    <td> <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Quotation</button> </td>          
                <%  
                out.println("</tr>");
            }                   
          %>
          </tbody>
      </table>  
</form>      
</div>
```

On the press of button i want to get data of selected columns of a particular row in next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move your data from one page to another using jsp You can use session Management or HttpServletRequest object request.

Using HttpServletRequest:

You can use javascript the following javascript function will alert the html table row index.

```
function saveRowID(row){

     alert(row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
     return false ;
}
```

Your HTML button code will be:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="saveRowID(this)"></button>
```

In javascript function row argument contains a collection of all td or th elements in a table row. You can iterate over them and save values in html form hidden fields and submit this form. 
On other page in jsp tags use HttpServletRequest request object to get form field values as:

```
 request.getParameter("formFieldId")
```